# Intercepting AJAX calls while web-scraping

Tags: python, ajax, web, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape an appStore, particularly the reviews for every app. The issue is that the reviews are dynamic and the client-side is making an AJAX POST call to get that data. The payload for this call is also being generated dynamically for every page. I was wondering if there is any way to intercept this request through code to get the payload, using which I could make a call using requests or any other library. I am able to make this call through POSTMAN using the parameters I get from inspect Network Activity utility of the web-browsers.

I could use selenium to scrape the finally loaded page- but it waits for the entire page to load which is highly un-optimized since I don't need to wait for the entirety of the page to load.

```
payload = "<This is dynamically created for every page and is constant for that given page>"
header = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
url = 'https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail'

r = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, headers=header)
```

I was wondering if its possible to get this payload through the scraper which can intercept all the AJAX calls made when it tries to scrape the base web-page.

Comment: You need javascript for this. I don't see how you can do it with python unless you used a custom python mitm proxy.

Comment: @pguardiario: thanks! I kinda thought the same, would try to optimize by putting hooks on browser network calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **scrape** a page that contains scripts and dynamic content, I would recommend using [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/).

It is a headless scriptable browser (can also be used in non-headless mode), it loads the page exactly like a browser with all its dynamic contents and scripts. So you can simply wait for the page to finish loading, and then read the rendered content

You can also use [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Also check this out: [a list of almost all headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers)

**UPDATE**

I know it's been some time, but I will post the answer to your comment here, in case you still need it or just for the sake of completeness:

In puppeteer you can asynchronously wait for a specific DOM node to appear on the page, or for some other events to occur. So you can continue on with your work after that and don't care about loading the rest of the page (although it will load in the background but you don't need to wait for it).

Comment: Thanks Amir, but the problem is optimization, I don't really want to randomly put time.sleep for every page- since there literally are thousands of web pages that need to be scraped.

Comment: You don't need to use time.sleep or anything like that. The phantomjs (or any other one of alternatives) handles everything. Check them out. These are standard tools of scraping

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, selenium or any other headless browser waits for the entire webpage to load before you can start scraping the contents of that page. Is there a way to stop loading the webpage at a certain point- when a particular ajax call has been made successfully- since I am interested in ONLY the response body that particular AJAX call?

Comment: I don't know about that. You can check their documentations

Comment: You should really stop recommending phantomjs because nobody is using it anymore. Puppeteer is the new big thing.